# Rowwise weighted.mean in dplyr using weights from another data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame with columns from different groups (here, `a` and `b`), and another data.frame containing the weights to perform a weighted mean:

```
test = data.frame(a.1=rep(2,5), b.1=rep(3,5), a.2=6:10, b.2=11:15)
tweights = data.frame(name=c('a.1', 'b.1', 'a.2', 'b.2'), 
                     w=c(0.2, 0.33, 0.8, 0.67))
```

For each line in `test`, I want to perform a weighted mean for the columns containing `a` with the weights given by their corresponding value in `tweights`, and the same for the columns with `b`.

What I tried to do:

```
test %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(awmean = weighted.mean(c(a.1, a.2), 
                                tweights$w[grepl('a', tweights$name)]),
         bwmean = weighted.mean(c(b.1, b.2), 
                                tweights$w[grepl('b', tweights$name)]))
```

This is working fine but this is not efficient nor elegant, I woudl like to avoid explicitly mentioning the column names (`a.1`, `a.2` etc), and the second part invoking `grepl` doesn't look very clean to me neither...

I tried something like this but it is wrong:

```
test %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(awmean = weighted.mean(contains('a'),
                                tweights$w[grepl('a', tweights$name)]))

Error: error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method 
for function 'weighted.mean': Error: could not find function "contains"
```

---

Note that I assume here that the order of the columns `a.1 : a.n` and the order of the corresponding lines in `tweights` is the same, which can be OK. A solution really taking care of the matching between the values and weights in `weighted.mean` would be even better...

Comment: `matrixStats::rowWeightedMeans(cbind(test$a.1, test$a.2 ), tweights$w[c(1, 3)])`

Comment: Thanks @Khashaa, but this requires that I know and explicitly mention all the column names containing `a`, and that I know the index of the corresponding weights in `tweights$w`. Any way to do something more generic?

Comment: Hmm are you happy with a long data shape, too? `test %>% 
  mutate(obs=1:n()) %>% 
  gather(name, value, -obs) %>% 
  left_join(tweights) %>% 
  separate(name, c("char", "num")) %>%
  group_by(obs, char) %>%
  mutate(wmean=weighted.mean(value, w)) %>%
  select(-w)`. (Needs `library(tidyr) )`.

Comment: Thanks @lukeA, very helpful and interesting (diidn't know `tidyr`) though it would indeed be less comfortable to work with the long shape. BTW, wouldn't `summarise(wmean=wmean[1]) ` piped to your command remove some redundant info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a custom function?

```
# get weighted means, for names beginning with a certain letter
getWM <- function(letter1) {
  rgx <- paste0('^', letter1)
  apply(test[, grep(rgx, names(test))], 1, weighted.mean,
        w = subset(tweights, grepl(rgx, name))$w )
}
```

Now you can just make a call like:

```
getWM('a')
[1] 5.2 6.0 6.8 7.6 8.4
```

Or, for all letters:

```
first_letters <- unique(gsub('[^a-z]', '', names(test)))
sapply(first_letters, getWM)

       a     b
[1,] 5.2  8.36
[2,] 6.0  9.03
[3,] 6.8  9.70
[4,] 7.6 10.37
[5,] 8.4 11.04
```

Comment: Thanks @arvi1000, very nice and working fine! I am still trying to find a (1-line) solution within `dplyr` syntax, but this is very helpful!